# Core Data, Relationship - store multiple selected rows to entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship

I need help - I want to store multiple selected rows from a tableView into one entity via relationship)

**Lets say I have this:**
CoreData-Model:
Entity_1 = Bags
Entity_2 = Items

The user can create "Bagmanymaby bags for the hole family) and "Items" he want to put into a selectet Bag. So If the family goes on holiday every familymember has its own bag with some items in it. Some items will be in every "Bag" (if the user select them.)

```
Bags (for):
- Carol 
- Bens 
- Eva

Items:
- toothbrush
- towel
- shoes
- hairbrush
- makeup
```

--> I know the way to only store one item into each entity (via relationship). But I need helpt to store several items at once in the selected "Bag"

*Ben only want to pick up: toothbrush and a towel*
*Carol pick up all the 5 items*
*Eva chooses toothbrush, makeup and shoes*

If I open the tableViewController all the items are listed:
I this I have to store all selected items into an array and then store the array to coredata. Who can give me a piece of code? Thank you for helping me.

FetchesResultsController:

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsCtrl: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> = {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true)
        //let catSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "kategorie", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        let fetchedCtrl = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        // an UserDefaults binden o.ä.:
        //NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCache(withName: "kategorieCache")

        fetchedCtrl.delegate = self
        return fetchedCtrl
    }()
```

TableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! detailsInterieur
        let items = fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.nameLabel?.text = items.itemName

        if let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            if (paths.contains(indexPath)){
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         print("select")
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         print("deselect")
}
```

**EDIT:**
I can find the selection with this code:

```
guard let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
            return
        }
```

This functions are generated automatically. But how can I use them in the right way?

```
@objc(addBag_RELObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToBag_REL(_ value: MyBag)

@objc(removeBag_RELObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromBag_REL(_ value: MyBag)

@objc(addBag_REL:)
@NSManaged public func addToBag_REL(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeBag_REL:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromBag_REL(_ values: NSSet)


@objc(addItem_RELObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToItem_REL(_ value: Item)

@objc(removeItem_RELObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromItem_REL(_ value: Item)

@objc(addItem_REL:)
@NSManaged public func addToItem_REL(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeitem_REL:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromitem_REL(_ values: NSSet)
```

Comment: Have you set up the relationship between `Bag` and `Item` in your data model? If that is done it should just be a matter of calling the correct method on your Bags object, something like `myBag.addToItems(myItem)`

Comment: Hi, yes I did - there is a relationships between bag(to one) and item(to many)

Comment: To me it sounds more like you have a many-to-many relationship since you don't create new items for each bag but rather select from existing items when you add them to a bag.. Anyway just add all Item objects to the selected bag and save your context.

Answer (score 3):

According to your scenario, **items** should be **to many** relationship on your **Bag** entity. In this case your `NSMangedObject` class for **Bag** or its extension (depending on what you choose in **codegen**) should have generated a method `@NSManaged public func addToItems(_ values: NSSet)`. 
You can get selected items from **tableView's var** `indexPathsForSelectedRows` generate **Items** and add them to your **bag** object using calling `addToItems(:)`.

But better way is to use **CoreData** wisely. In your case **Item** will have a `bag` property on it (as per relationship) so when you create an **item** and assign it a valid **bag** object it will automatically update the other side of the relationship.

Comment: I edit my post... So it is nor clear to me, how I can use this function addToItems(:) - I have seen them, yes... but - If I understand right I have to store my selected items in an array via "indexPathsForSelectedRows" guard let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
            return
        }

Comment: your bags relationship on item should be 'to one', so first four methods does't make sense, check your model. And create a bag managed object, then for each of your selected index path create an item object and assign the bag object to each item.

Comment: hmm I think it is many-to-many? One bag can have all or several items and items can be in all or some bags.

Comment: a single item instance cannot be in multiple bags. e.g a a towel cannot belong to two bags. You have to create two separate towels for each bag.

Comment: hmmm ... but the "Item" is not this ONE TOWEL - the item I want to choose is, like a categorie "towel" - so in ech bag has to be one towel - not this explizit towel such a towel.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have the selected items in `selectedRow` as above and that you have some property with the currently selected bag, say `selectedBag` then do

```
guard let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
    return
} 

for path in selectedRows {
    let item = fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: path.row)
    selectedBag.addToItem_REL(item)
}
```

Then call `save()` on your managed object context.